# Magento 2 Braintree Payment Method Error For Second Website

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, multi-website, braintree

I've set 2 websites us and uk.

Signed up for Braintree sandbox account.

Created 2 Merchant Account ID.

1- **uk_maid**.

2- **us_maid**.

Magento admin **Stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment Method** on the left changed  **Store View:** **uk_website** then configured Braintree entered all details plus `Merchant ID` = **uk_maid** saved.

Again same process as above but `Merchant ID` will be **us_maid**:

Magento admin **Stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment Method** on the left changed  **Store View:** **us_website** then configured Braintree entered all the details and `Merchant ID` = **us_maid** saved.

Placed order in **uk** website everything works payment were taken and appear in my sanbox Braintree dashboard under the **uk_maid** which is set to default.

Now using **us** website in ../checkout/#payment as soon as check radio box Braintree as payment option :
[image]

In console:
[image]

I don't get it why can't use alternative merchant id for us website?

Is this a bug? Anyone have had this set up any experienced the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: This maybe an issue ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5910

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue.

For me direct place where the issue happened is here:

> vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Http.php : 175

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
file_put_contents('/var/www/magento/var/log/braintree.log', $response . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

And response was:

```
<errors>Unauthorized</errors>
```

How I solved it I really don't know. Let me explain what was configured and what I did:

In magento backend there are two settings:

**Merchant ID** and **Merchant Account ID**
Pay attention! These are two DIFFERENT settings.

Let's move to braintree website. 
https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/*************/merchant_accounts/info

You may see:

> Merchant ID
>
> Your merchant ID is a unique identifier for your entire gateway account. This value is required to connect your API calls to the Braintree gateway.
>
> Merchant Accounts
>
> Below is a list of payment methods and currencies you are currently accepting. The merchant account ID is a unique identifier for a specific merchant account in your gateway, and is used to specify which merchant account to use when creating a transaction.

Now let's move to

> Braintree website / Settings / User and Roles / {edit any role}

Scroll to the bottom and you will see:

> Merchant Accounts
>
> Allow the user to search for and manipulate transactions and disputes tied to the following merchant accounts (in accordance with their roles):
>
> All
>
> (If 'All' is selected, any merchant accounts added in the future will be added to the user automatically)
>
> All Sub-merchant Accounts
>
> {Here are your merchant accounts}

**I'm not sure but I think you need to select checkbox "All"** and on magento side leave Merchant Account ID field !!empty. (Or put save value, as configured in braintree account)

As for me it started working after I selected "All" and made empty field.
BUT! When I filled this value again to doublecheck - the issue didn't reproduce anymore. So I can't 100% be sure, that this is silver bullet.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @zhartaunik

Yes Merchant ID and Merchant Account ID is the cause.

I get the issue when I set value of Merchant ID for Merchant Account ID.

it better to leave Merchant Account ID blank then I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me @V.Tran answer helps, it better to leave Merchant Account ID blank

Answer (score -2):

Based on [this issue from Magento's Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7587), Braintree is not configurable through the store view within the Magento 2 core extension. It needs to be configured through the website view.